# Is there anyone that knows what the following code possibly does?

Tags: c, encoding, utf-8

```
/* utf-8: 0xc0, 0xe0, 0xf0, 0xf8, 0xfc */
static unsigned char _mblen_table_utf8[] = 
{
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 1, 1
};
```

I bet it has something to do with the encodings,

but how exactly it works?

**UPDATE**

```
        while (str < ptr)
        {
            j = mblen[(*str)];
            tree_nput(r->tree, cr, sizeof(struct rule_item), str, j);
            str += j;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I what context? This is just the declaration of an array. It doesn't *do* much really.

Comment: You should also find and post the code that uses _mblen_table_utf8

Comment: It's a rather hackish and **incorrect** table of UTF-8 multibyte character lengths, but it should work as long as the input data is known to be well-formed. (As for what's wrong, C0 and C1 bytes are incorrectly coded as 2-byte character starter bytes in the table. Also the 5- and 6- byte ones are wrong. UTF-8 is at most 4 bytes to a character.)

Comment: @R.. ,it seems C0 and C1 bytes are actually 2-byte character starter bytes according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf8#Description, what do you think is wrong ?

Comment: Please show me a character that begins with C0 or C1. None exists.

Comment: @R..,I don't know such a character, but it's in the range of `110xxxxx~1110xxxx` specified by the standard,right?

Comment: @new_perl `C0` and `C1` would only be able to start a character that could also be represented with a single byte, in which case the shorter single byte representation should be used.  Apparently there are cases where `C0 80` is used, but it's not normally allowed.

Comment: @Dmitri ,I have read through the wiki page about UTF-8,and it doesn't mention about that, why do you think `C0` and `C1` is special?IMO `C0` is just a border of the range in the UTF-8 standard,like `E0`(1110xxxx) and `F0`(11110xxx),nothing special.

Comment: @new_perl You just need to read a little further down: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences

Comment: The first (lowest value) two-byte character is `U+0080`, whose representation is `C2 80`. There is no character whose representation begins with `C0` or `C1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a character in a multibyte string has a variable length, this table maps each character to a length.

The last 64 characters are wider than one byte, having lengths of `2` to `6`.

The usage would be something like that:

```
unsigned char current_char = *mbstr;

for (i = 0; i < _mblen_table_utf8[current_char]; i++) {
  /* treat *mbstr++ as a part of the current character */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Historically, each character was coded on 7 bits (then 8 bits) which was more than enough to encode european languages alphabets.

Only the 128 first characters were common to everyone, the remaining 128 were standardized through codepages ([ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) is an example).

The need to encode longer alphabet languages such as Chinese resulted in the [Unicode effort](http://unicode.org/) were each character is coded on several bytes.

[UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a way to encode Unicode characters in an efficient, variable code-length way. This means that the first byte you read determines the length of the character byte-sequence.

Basically, your table is a lookup-table to check how many bytes is a character that start from the byte you use as table index. You will see another version of this table [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout) with explanations.

I added the table indexes as comments to make it clearer:

```
/* utf-8: 0xc0, 0xe0, 0xf0, 0xf8, 0xfc */
static unsigned char _mblen_table_utf8[] = 
{
/*0x00*/    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
/*0x10*/    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
/*0x20*/    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
/*0x30*/    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
/*0x40*/    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
/*0x50*/    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
/*0x60*/    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
/*0x70*/    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
/*0x80*/    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
/*0x90*/    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
/*0xA0*/    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
/*0xB0*/    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
/*0xC0*/    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
/*0xD0*/    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
/*0xE0*/    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
/*0xF0*/    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 1, 1
};
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more about `the remaining 128 were standardized through codepages `?

Comment: @new_perl Sure. 128 smallest bytes are standardized into ASCII. The 128 upper bytes are OS/language dependant. The translation between the character value and its glyph depends on the codepage we _were_ using. i.e. character 0x80 is not defined in codepage ISO-8859-1 and equals '€' in codepage Windows-1252. Simply put: codepages are glyphs lookup tables that are strongly language and OS dependent. See the [Common character encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Common_character_encodings) for further details.

Comment: code point(the term I heard elsewhere) and character value are the same thing, is it right?

Comment: sorry, never took the time to find out what codepoints really were.

Comment: @new_perl when talking about Unicode, "codepoint" is _like_ a character value, yes; it's sort of a character ID number.  I think the idea was to separate the idea of IDs for the characters (codepoints) from the values of the bytes used to represent them.  For a given character, the codepoint is always the same but the bytes used to represent them depend on the encoding.

Comment: @new_perl The codepoint is just a number, corresponding to a specific character.  It's just that the way that number is represented in a string depends on the encoding; the bytes that represent it will be different for UTF-8 than for UTF-16, for example.  So the codepoint for 'あ' is 0x3042, but the representation could be `{0x30, 0x42}` or `{0x42, 0x30}` or `{0xe3, 0x81, 0x82}`, etc. depending on the encoding (the last one being UTF-8 if I didn't mess up the conversion).

Answer (score 1):

The array appears to be a lookup table for determining the number of bytes in a UTF-8 character, given the first byte.  Basically the first byte (as an unsigned value) is used as an index into the array, and the element at that index gives the length of the byte sequence for the UTF-8 character.

Invalid and mid-sequence bytes seem to map to 1-byte in this table, so if encountered out of place the code using this table would probably treat them as single characters (unless it specifically ignores them).

One use for a table like this is for counting characters in a UTF-8 string (not bytes, but Unicode characters).  Each time you count a character, you look up the length and move ahead by the length of the character's byte sequence instead of moving ahead one byte... it works well as long as you start at the beginning of a character and the string is valid UTF-8 all the way through.

Answer (score 0):

Without any further details, the code above does exactly this: it declares a static unsigned char array and initializes it with the values inside the curly brackets.

Comment: To be precise, this code *defines* an array and doesn't just *declare* it. A mere *declaration* doesn't involve initialisation: http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter2/variable_declaration.html

Comment: As in... it declares and initializes it. You can't have a definition without a declaration...